# Decorate data with containing class enum

Tags: c#

I have an interface with multiple implementations:

```
public enum Source { Source1, Source2 }

public interface IMessageClient
{
    Source Source { get; }
    Response<string[]> GetMessages();
    Response<string> GetMessage();
}

public class Response<T>
{
    public Source Source { get; set;}
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to decorate my responses with the type/source of the messages (currently `Source` above), without explicitly setting it in all of my response methods, i.e. setting in on each `Response` instance manually. Is that possible?

```
public class MessageClient : IMessageClient
{
    public Source Source => Source.Source1;
    public Response<string[]> GetMessages()
    {
        return new Response<string[]>
        {
            Source = Source, Data = new[] {"1", "2"}
        };
    }

    public Response<string> GetMessage()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To elaborate, currently I need to set `Source` manually on each response. What are my options as far as automating that goes? I just want it decorated from the containing class without explicitly setting it on each response.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly but know that you can loop through all enum values by `foreach (Source item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Source)))`, maybe this'll help you?

Comment: I can only think of putting optional parameter in interface methods, like so: `Response<string[]> GetMessages(Source source = -1);`
`Response<string> GetMessage(Source source = -1);`
When the method has -1, you'll know that the enum wasn't passed (assuming no source enum takes -1 as value).

Comment: Please edit your question to make it more clear. It may be that you want to define a custom attribute, applied to each implementing class of the `IMessageClient` interface. Or maybe you want to use some kind of "aspect oriented programming" tool to inject logic in the response methods themselves? Or maybe you want some base implementation that can do the work for you? It's not at all clear what you mean.

Comment: Do you mean you want to automatically set the value of the Source in Response class every time when you create a new Response instance?

Comment: @DoubleE Pretty much, yes

Comment: And what defines what source to use? Something in "Data"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think (hope) I got it.

Can you inherit from a base class?

```
public abstract class BaseMessageClient : IMessageClient
{
    public Source Source { get; protected set; }

    public Response<T> CreateResponse(T data)
    {
        return new .... Source = this.Source ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Or you can put the CreateResponse into the interface with a default implementation (since .NET 5 afair). Down side: I think you always need a cast to the interface.
`(this as IMessageClient).CreateResponse(data)`

[EDIT] Remark: All parameters that are needed to create a valid Response could be params for the constructor. In this case I like the new records.

```
public record Response<T>(Source Source, T Data);
```